# Nested container not appearing inline even if nest has overflow:hidden

Tags: css, html

I have 2 `<span>`s nested inside a div like;

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="content" style="background-color: #CC0033;">foo</span>
  <span class="content" style="background-color: #FF6600;">bar</span>
</div>
```

and here is the css;

```
.container{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content{
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  border: solid 2px #333333;
  float: left;
}
```

But the second child goes to bottom after first child, and is not visible inline. The width of container is fixed. But I want to completely display first span and partially display second one.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/rctac/)** is the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you have to wrap your spans in a block elements that's as wide or wider than the sum of the span widths.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rctac/3/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <span class="content" style="background-color: #CC0033;">foo</span>
        <span class="content" style="background-color: #FF6600;">bar</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width:200px;
}
```

Inline and inline block elements will wrap to the next line if there isn't enough space horizontally for them to fit. By wrapping them in a block level element, you can shove that down your container's throat and force them to appear next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Change your container to `display: inline-block` and remove the width style.

```
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rctac/1/)

This results in the container only taking up as much space as it needs, but everything remaining inline.

[image]

Optionally also add a `max-width: 100%` on the container, so they'll wrap instead of going off the screen (e.g. on phones).

Comment: What if he wants/needs the width on the container?

Comment: The elements inside of it have specified widths, so it doesn't matter.  It just won't crash and burn if you increase those widths to 97px, and don't have a CSS reset/normalizer.